# What is the right syntax to define swagger response schema, in a .proto file?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, proto

What is the right syntax to define swagger response schema, in a .proto file?
I've tried the stuff below, but my compilation fails, complaining about :

```
Error while parsing option value for "openapiv2_operation": Message type "grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_swagger.options.JSONSchema" has no field named "item".
```

I've also tried "items" but without luck.
For some reasons, I am not finding a proper documentation on how to define this in a proto file.
I've managed to find a bunch of example though, but none actually covers this scenario.

```
....
rpc ListOrganizations (ListOrganizationsRequest) returns (ListOrganizationsResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get : "/v4/organizations"
    };
    option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_swagger.options.openapiv2_operation) = {
      description: "Get organizations list";
      summary: "Fetch the user organizations list";
      tags: "Organizations";
      responses: {
        key: "200"
        value: {
          description: "On successful response";
          schema: {
            json_schema: {
              type: ARRAY;
              item:{
                "test": STRING
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
......
```

The response structure will have to eventually match this message:

```
message Organization {
  string id = 1;  // e.g. '/organizations/117'
  string displayName = 2;
  OrganizationType type = 3; // Type of organization
  repeated OrganizationMember members = 4;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp create_time = 5; // The time and date at with the Organization was createdVy
  google.protobuf.Timestamp update_time = 6;
}
 
message ListOrganizationsRequest {
  OrganizationType type = 1;
  OrganizationView view = 2;
}
 
message ListOrganizationsResponse {
  repeated Organization organizations = 1;
  int32 totalSize = 2; // total count of organizations that match request.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I managed to find a solution by digging into openapiv2.proto
Still, it will be nice to have somewhere on the public domain, some proper docs on this.

For whoever is interested, the schema definition should look something like this:

```
 schema: {
            json_schema: {
              type: ARRAY;
              ref: '#/definitions/mix.api.ListOrganizationsResponse'
            }
          }
```